# How to find out which platform architectures does my app support?

Tags: android, android-build

I am getting some crash reports in the play store developer console and all these crashes are happening on `armeabi-v7a` platform devices. Here is the crash report :

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XWUGML4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
pid: 19738, tid: 19738, name: something.android  >>> com.something.android <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
    r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 40baf1a0
    r4 deadd00d  r5 0000020c  r6 42a2de60  r7 40b44c51
    r8 401091f4  r9 58220c40  sl 41ea7a70  fp befad3ec
    ip 4d1a4001  sp befad0e8  lr 00000001  pc 40b3f33c  cpsr 60000030
    d0  000000000000000f  d1  4000000000000000
    d2  ffffffffffffffff  d3  ffffffffffffffff
    d4  8000000000000000  d5  3fcef049fb9094d1
    d6  3f00000000000000  d7  3f8000003f800000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 000000000000000e  d17 0400050101010df7
    d18 4146605000000000  d19 0065004e005f0061
    d20 3f8948b0fcd6e9e0  d21 3fe555b0aaeac752
    d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
    d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
    d26 40026bb1bbb55516  d27 4000000000000000
    d28 40008df2d49d41f1  d29 3fb0f4a31edab38b
    d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3f4de16b9c24a98f
    scr 60000010

backtrace:
    #00  pc 0004633c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+67)
    #01  pc 0004ad8f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+146)
    #02  pc 0004bc6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #03  pc 0029b609  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #04  pc 0028f899  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #05  pc 0028f973  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #06  pc 00295c99  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #07  pc 0001e48c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #08  pc 0004e95b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
    #09  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #10  pc 0002be40  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #11  pc 00060d6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+350)
    #12  pc 00068a2f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #13  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #14  pc 0002be40  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #15  pc 00060aad  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
    #16  pc 0004a53b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #17  pc 00054aa3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #18  pc 00055fcb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+378)
    #19  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
    #20  pc 0000dc4f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
    #21  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
    40b3f31c f8d54a18 462034cc f44f447a f7d77100  
    40b3f32c 2200ebc4 5d114615 e004b9a9 4c0d4780  
    40b3f33c f7d77025 4910ecfe 4a102006 447a4479  
    40b3f34c eb7cf7d7 f7d72000 4b0dec34 6dd8447b  
    40b3f35c d1eb2800 3201e7eb f5b2186d d0ea7f00  
    40b3f36c bf00e7e1 deadd00d 0006b96e fffffe5c  
    40b3f37c 0006fe8a 0004fb0b 0004eeee 00050dae  
    40b3f38c 0006fe44 4604b570 68406806 f1a0e005  
    40b3f39c 46280518 fc9ef7f3 42b04628 6820d1f7  
    40b3f3ac 68a1b128 f0221a0a f7ff0107 4620fe6a  
    40b3f3bc 0000bd70 f00fb570 4b3dfd03 f8d3447b  
    40b3f3cc b10803cc f8d6f01e 25004c3a 6c20447c  
    40b3f3dc eb22f7d7 64256ea0 eb1ef7d7 66a56f20  
    40b3f3ec eb1af7d7 f00c6725 f00cf9e1 f8d4fc0f  
    40b3f3fc 28030098 f02dd101 f00ffef5 492efa47  
    40b3f40c f8914479 b1322033 2003492c 44794a2c  

code around lr:
    00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
    000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

I think I am not supporting the above architecture, so how do I find out in Android Studio or using terminal, which all platforms my apk supports? And suppose, if I am actually not supporting some architecture, what should I do to enable the support?

Comment: "all these crashes are happening on armeabi-v7a platform devices" -- that's because the vast majority of Android devices run `armeabi-v7a` CPUs.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I support those devices?

Comment: why dont you start by giving us what your actual crash stacktrace is of the crash, the one you gave is not a stacktrace

Comment: @tyczj the app crashes as soon as you start it, on these devices. So I am getting nothing on Crashlytics. This is the only thing I got and I got in from play store developer console.

Comment: "How do I support those devices?" -- probably you already do. Unless you are crashing on ~80% of Android devices, your problem is not specific to CPU architecture.

Comment: @CommonsWare but, if there is a way to verify which all platforms does my apk support, I can be sure that the problem does not lie in the architecture, rather on some code that I have written. Also, I don't understand anything the above crash report says.

Comment: "if there is a way to verify which all platforms does my apk support" -- not really, because "support" is a very nebulous term. "I don't understand anything the above crash report says" -- this is a dump from a crash in native code. Specifically, you seem to be crashing in `libdvm.so` (which AFAIK is the Dalvik interpreter) in some callback from `libwebcore.so` (which AFAIK is the Android 4.3-and-earlier `WebView` library). None of that is directly from your app. So, I'd focus on where you are using `WebView`, directly and indirectly (e.g., ad libraries).

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using `WebView` only at one place and that too is not at the forefront of the app. In these 3 phones, the app crashes as soon as you start it. So, what should I do?

Comment: Buy one of the devices, so you can test this in the lab. Reproduce the crash. Then, start commenting things out to eventually isolate what code of yours (or code of a third party's) is triggering the crash.